# Minimal rank of a permutation resolution of a $G$-lattice

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, finite-groups, group-cohomology

Let $G$ be a finite group.
By a *$G$-lattice* I mean a finitely generated free abelian group $L$ with an action of $G$. 
One says that $L$ is a *permutation lattice* if $L$ has a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis permuted by $G$.

> **Question.**
>   For a $G$-lattice $L$, 
>   how can one compute the minimal $\mathbb{Z}$-rank of a permutation $G$-lattice $P$ such that there exists a surjective $G$-morphism $P\to L$ ?

I expect an answer in terms of some kind of group cohomology. I would be happy to get an answer at least in the cases when $G$ is a $p$-group, an abelian $p$-group, a cyclic $p$-group.